# Condition for the validity of a property of limits

Tags: limits

While studying limits , I came across the following identity :

Let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = l$ and $ \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = m$. If $l$ and $m$ exist , then

$\lim_{x \to a}(f+g)(x) =  \lim_{x \to a}f(x) +\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$

My question is , is the above identity valid if and only if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are indeterminate individually ?

For example , recently I tried a question ,

If $f(x) = \frac{2}{x-3} , g(x) = \frac{x-3}{x+4}$ and $h(x)= -\frac{2(2x+1)}{x^2+x-12}$ then find the value of

$ \lim_{x \to 3} [f(x) + g(x) + h(x)]$

As we can clearly see that $g(x)$ is not indeterminate for the given limit and hence not all of the functions are indeterminate . Hence when I tried to split the limit and solve , I was unable to get the correct answer. However after taking LCM the whole thing becomes indeterminate and using L’Hospital’s Rule I was able to arrive at the correct answer. So is the rule imperative that all functions must be of indeterminate form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity is valid

- if $m,l\in \mathbb{R}$ or
- if one is $\in \mathbb{R}$ and one $\infty$ or
- if both are $\pm \infty$ with the same sign (both $+\infty$ or both $-\infty$)

that is in all the cases which don't lead to an indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$.

Note that you can't apply the result to the limit

$$\lim_{x \to 3} [f(x) + g(x) + h(x)]$$

since the single limits for $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ do not exist for $x \to 3$.

And we cannot apply neither for one side limit since

$$\lim_{x \to 3^+} [f(x)]=+\infty \qquad \lim_{x \to 3^-} [f(x)]=-\infty$$

but

$$\lim_{x \to 3^+} [h(x)]=-\infty \qquad \lim_{x \to 3^-} [h(x)]=+\infty$$

Comment: Thank you , so you mean that the identity is invalid , if one of the limits is finite but the other is infinite ? Meaning both limits should either be finite or infinite together ?

Comment: @Aditi Of course also the case $\infty + c$ is valid I add this case.

Comment: Do you mean that it is possible to split the limit if one of them is determinate , and the other is indeterminate ?

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean by ‘same sign’ ? And in what case is the identity actually invalid ?

Comment: We can have that $\lim_{x \to 3} [f(x) + g(x) + h(x)]$ exist but on or more of the single limits for f,g,h don't exist.

Comment: Then why was it wrong to split the limit in that question ?

Comment: Observe that $\lim_{x \to 3} [f(x)]$ doesn't exist and the rule applies only when the limit exist. And also for g(x) anfd h(x) we can't define a limit for $x \to 3$.

Comment: I’m sorry but you just said that the identity is applicable even if one of $l,m$ is infinite ? So it’s possible that one of the limits does not exist and we can still split it right ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't check in detail for all function, but in this case suffices that $f(x)$ has not limit for $x\to 3$ thus we can't apply the rule. What we could try is evaluate separately for $x\to 3^-$ and for $x\to 3^+$

Comment: If I'm not wrong for $x\to 3^+$ we have $f(x)\to +\infty$ and $h(x)\to -\infty$ thus we can't apply the rule neither for the one sided limit.

Comment: Oh now I get the reason !

Comment: No it is a very different concept we say that $\lim_{x \to 3} [f(x)]$ doesn't exists since $$\lim_{x \to 3^+} [f(x)]\neq\lim_{x \to 3^-} [f(x)]$$

Comment: Yes you are correct , $h(x)$ will tend to negative infinity so its not correct to apply the rule

Comment: @Aditi Well done! The story is all this, when limit exists and the sum don't lead to an indeterminate form you can sum up each limit!

Comment: @Aditi It is just as the case for the finction $\frac1x$ for $x\to 0$, does it exist?

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your great help !

Comment: Oh yes it doesn’t exist . My bad,  I’m sorry

Comment: @Aditi It's a plesure! and Always a way to check also my knowledge! Explain is difficult as or more than learn! And it is also a good way to learn indeed! Bye